# Incorrect syntax near 'CONTAINS' for Dedicated SQL Pool in Azure Synpase

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-synapse

This is the query that I'm trying to run in Azure Synapse:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.someTable WHERE CONTAINS(someColumn, 'abc123')
```

However I keep getting this error without really knowing what's wrong witht he SQL function:

> Parse error at line: 7, column: 7: Incorrect syntax near 'CONTAINS'.

The column that I'm concerned with is `someColumn(nvarchar(300), null)`

Is there anything that I could be missing in order for the function to work?

Comment: You probably need `SELECT * FROM dbo.someTable WHERE someColumn LIKE '%abc123%'` - [`CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is a full text indexing predicate and not relevant to Synapse

Comment: Does that mean I can't use CONTAINS in Azure Synapse?

Comment: As you can see from the docs, it's not supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16 you can only use it in SQL Server on-premises, and Azure SQL Server, not Azure Synapse

Comment: I definitely missed that. Thank you for the information!

Comment: @MartinSmith & seanpai - Would you like to post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?